# Dynamically include array object variables in the HTML in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I am new to the Angular 6. Here is my problem.

In the Component:

```
 ngOnInit() {

                this.cols = [
                    { field: 'col1', header: 'Column 1', filterMatchMode: 'contains' },
                    { field: 'col2', header: 'Column 2', filterMatchMode: 'contains' },
                     ...
                ];
this.selectedColumns = this.cols;

    }
```

In the HTML:

```
 <p-table [columns]="selectedColumns" >
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns;">
                  <div [ngClass]="{'has-error': col.field.invalid && col.field.touched }">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="newRecord[col.field]" name="{{col.field}}" #{{col.field}}="ngModel" required type="text" pInputText [style]="{'width':'100%'}" class="form-control form-control-sm search-input" pattern="[0-9]+" />
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="col.field.invalid && col.field.touched" class="td-error-msg">
                    Valid input is required.
                  </div>
                </th>
 </p-table>
```

I am getting issue where when I try to check and insert the dynamic value "col.field" in the ngIf and Angular id.

```
1. *ngIf="col.field.invalid && col.field.touched"
2. name="{{col.field}}" #{{col.field}}="ngModel"
```

I am trying to provide validation for the input field with error message.

Comment: have you tried adding a `col.field &&` into the front of the ngIf? it might be blowing up if it tries checking and it hasn't created the record yet

Comment: This is just a guess, but I don't think it's possible to create variable names dynamically like you're doing here: ```#{{col.field}}="ngModel"```. However, the template variable should be scoped to the template of the current item in the ngFor, meaning you can say #field="ngModel" and use it in the ngIf like ```*ngIf="field.invalid && field.touched"``` and it should work... I think?

Comment: I have only worked with angularJS, so I could be wrong, but from what I see, you are checking `col.field` is `invalid` and `touched`, but `col.field` is a string, not an object, so it would not have an `invalid` or `touched` property. In angularJS, you would have a name on the element and check that. I believe it is possible to check dynamic names by using `{{}}`. Try wrapping `col.field` in `{{}}` and see if that works. As for the dynamic variables, I do not know. That is not a feature of angularJS to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, i have tried the same. But it is throwing errors. No luck.

Comment: Are you trying to make a new record using using p-table?

Comment: @Calidus Yes, with validation feature.

Comment: I'm just going to dump this stackblitz I made here. I think it addresses what you were having trouble with. However, I would also think about what Calidus suggested as well, since he makes some good points. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mefkxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Wingnod. Perfect! Could you put this into answer section? So that i will accept it. And Can you explain how the 'field' is working here?

Comment: @Raja Great! It's good that it suits your needs. Hopefully the answer I wrote makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template variable with a static name, such as `#field` (or whatever name you like), and since it is scoped to the item, there will be no naming conflicts.

`<input [(ngModel)]="newRecord[col.field]" name="{{col.field}}" #field="ngModel"... />
...
<div *ngIf="field.invalid && field.touched" class="td-error-msg">
   Valid input is required.
</div>`

`field` will always refer to the input of the current item. The `*ngFor` structural directive creates a template for each item, each with its own scope. This should be the easiest solution over dynamically creating template variable names.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mefkxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing prime ng p-table component, you are trying to use column headers as a input form. If you want to use the table to input new data it would be much easier to just create a `<p-table>` with a single row and use the built in features of primeng like the `OnEditComplete()` event to trigger your validation. I would also ask yourself if you really need dynamic columns? Do you need to use a table? Could you just make a form and use the validation build into prime ng?

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/validation